# Issue with PHP Script and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have issue with my PHP script.
My script update values of existing users or adding them .

But I want add new variable to the "system" and database called  "death".

How PHP/MySQL get info about data? 
This is not very significant but here is the script.

(this is not php, its working)

##SCRIPT SEND DATA

```
        (player_get_unique_id, reg1, reg0),
    (player_get_gold, reg2, reg0),
    (player_get_death_count, reg3, reg0),
    (str_store_player_username, s0, reg0),
    (send_message_to_url, "@http://MyAwesomeIP/killrecord.php?unique%5Fid={reg1}&local%5Fid={reg0}&event=2&username={s0}&Gold={reg2}&death={reg3}"),
```

As you can see , there I send 4 variables . 
(s0,reg0,reg1,reg2,reg3)

But currently I use only three in my php script/database

(s0,reg0,reg1,reg2)

Everything was fine until I added the table "death"

I simply add it to database , no php coding etc.

When I did this, new information does not reach the database.

But when I remove the "death" tables again, new information comes again.

Can someone help me to fix this issue?
My PhP script which receive data from ####SEND DATA SCRIPT and send it to database is here. Thanks for any advice!Cheers Piter.

```
  #  killrecord.php
 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['event']) && isset($_GET['unique_id']) && 
 isset($_GET['local_id'])&& isset($_GET['username']))
{
  $unique_id=$_GET["unique_id"];
     $local_id=$_GET["local_id"];//for feedback only
     $username=$_GET["username"];

  $db_handle = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword", "dbname") 
or die("|-1");
  if($db_handle)
    if($_GET['event'] == 1)//get player gold
    {
      $sql_result = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Gold FROM tabelka WHERE 
Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
      $result = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_result); 

      if (!$result)
      {//the player is not in the database, so we will insert it
        mysqli_query($db_handle, "INSERT INTO tabelka 
(Unique_Id,Username,Gold VALUES($unique_id, '$username', 0)");
        echo "1|$unique_id|$local_id|0";//and we will echo gold as 0
      }else{
        echo "1|$unique_id|$local_id|1|".$result[0]; 
      }
    }else if($_GET['event'] == 2)//set player gold
    {
      if(isset($_GET['gold']))//if the gold is set
      {
        $gold = $_GET['gold'];
        mysqli_query($db_handle, "UPDATE tabelka SET Gold='$gold' WHERE 
 Unique_Id = '$unique_id'");
      }
    }
  mysqli_close($db_handle);
}

?>
```

So simply . Add new "death" column to my table cause  a problem that the database does not create/update/receive  new data.

Comment: You may want to check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out what may be going on.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**